# Creating a GTK theme, but Qt and Java apps are not affected, and title bar button layout is ugly

Tags: java, themes, gtk, qt, mate

I'm playing with a gtk2 / gtk3 theme which I use in the Mate desktop.

Everything is looking well, even gtk3 apps, but I still have 3 important issues:

1. Java apps ignore the theme
2. QT apps ignore the theme
3. I'm using those nice ubuntu 10 title bar buttons, but the problem is, when only the close button appears, the title bar looks ugly. Can I make it so that it shows the two other buttons, but disabled? I don't know how Ubuntu 10 handled this.

Here's a screenshot showing the 3 problems (above is a small java app, below is a Qt app):
[image: Screenshot]

Under my previous desktop environments, Unity and Cinnamon, both apps seemed to be taking the right theme correctly, but I did not use my custom theme yet.

Cinnamon is based on gnome-shell by the way, and mate is a gnome2-fork.

Please note that the shown java app explicitely tries to load the gtk theme at runtime. By default, java apps don't, but this one has the necessary code, which worked in unity and cinnamon.

Any suggestions how I could make my theme better so these problems disappear? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A usually problem whith Gnome, 
Its a gnome-centric or GTK-centric. If Qt programs are nice in a Gnome, is for Qt, not for Gnome.

Comment: Yes I noticed I could fix the Qt problem with qtconfig-qt4. I'll do a clean reinstall of ubuntu because I'm getting windows 95 styles in most applications, when switching to unity... Changing the theme or logging on a clean user account did not fix the problem.